# if statement doesn't work?

Tags: c

wordCur is a string of capital letters, and dictionary is an array of strings, no matter what I input into wordCur, I am always returned 0.

Edit: I updated the code a little bit, and added an abridged version of the rest of the program for some context. As it is shown here, it just crashes when it gets to checkValid

```
int main() {
    FILE *ifp;
    ifp = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
    int* lDist[26];
    int* lUsed[26];
    int dictLen;
    int i;
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &dictLen);
    char dictionary[dictLen][7];
    char* letters[7];
    int scoreCur = 0;
    int scoreHi = 0;
    char wordCur[7];
    char wordHi[7];
    int isWord = 0;





//reads the dictionary into the array
for (i = 0; i < dictLen; i++) {
    fscanf(ifp, "%s", &dictionary[i]);
}
    scanf("%s", wordCur);
    isWord = checkValid(wordCur, dictLen, dictionary);
    if (isWord == 1) {
        scoreCur = calcScore(wordCur);
    }



//fclose(ifp); not sure why, but this causes a crash
return 0;
}


int checkValid (char *wordCur,int dictLen, char dictionary[dictLen]) {
    int valid = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < dictLen; i++){
    int helper = strcmp(wordCur, dictionary[i]);
    if (helper = 0){
        valid = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not valid C: `dictionary` is neither an array, nor a pointer.

Comment: I think you miss a '*' before word **dictionary**

Comment: I suspect you are missing some * characters from your code... And you may want to use strncmp rather than comparing pointer addresses to check for string equality

Comment: I tried all of that, doesn't help, when, i add in print statements to check the values, they come out correctly, it really seems like a problem with the if statement its self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should probably look more like this:

```
int checkValid(const char *wordCur,       // word to search for (string)
               int dictLen,               // no of entries in dictionary
               char dictionary[][7])      // dictionary (array of strings)
{
    int valid = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < dictLen; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(wordCur, dictionary[i]) == 0)
        {
            valid = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: Specifying `dictlen` as the number of elements to `dictionary` in the prototype has no effect.  It could be argued that it is documentary, but it can mislead.

Comment: that just makes it crash, adding [7] (the max length of words in the dictionary) after the [dictlen] makes it run, however, it still always returns 0

Comment: You need to post the calling code, showing how you have defined and initialised `dictionary` etc.

Comment: should I just post my whole program?

Comment: If it's a small amount of code then yes, otherwise reduce it to a reasonable size which just includes the checkValid function and the calling code.

Comment: I updated it to show an abridged version of my code, hopefully that can clear things up

Comment: OK - I have updated the function to match your definition of dictionary. BTW, it looks like you either have warnings disabled or you are just ignoring compiler warnings - always compile with `gcc -Wall ...` or equivalent and take notice of all warnings and fix them - this will save you a lot of debugging time.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly what exactly was the problem?

Comment: As I said above, if you had had compiler warnings enabled the compiler would have told you exactly what the problem was - the definition of dictionary in the calling code was not compatible with the way you had defined dictionary in your checkValid function.

Answer (score 2):

> wordCur is a string of capital letters

```
int checkValid (char wordCur,int dictLen, char dictionary[dictLen])
```

No, `wordCur` is a single character. Not a string. A string in C is represented as an array of characters, terminated by a character with the value 0. You need a pointer argument, `char *wordCur`.

Answer (score 0):

*wordCur is a string of capital letters, and dictionary is an array of strings*

Try this:

```
int checkValid (const char *wordCur,int dictLen, const char *dictionary[])
```

By the way, you keep searching, even after you found what you are looking for, and the comaprison is wrong anyway for strings.  I suggest:

```
for (i = 0; i < dictLen; i++){  
    if (strcmp(wordCur, dictionary[i]) == 0){  
        valid = 1;  
        break;
    }  
}
```